# Validation failed for one or more entities. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting following error when I try to create a row for `CommentReview` model via action `CreateComment`.

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

I'm doing something wrong with data I'm sending to my model, but I don't know what. I also tried  with`(DbEntityValidationException e)` method without success since I couldn't make it work with my code as I'm not an experienced coder and new to MVC.

**Code below is from my controller:**

```
// GET: Review/Create
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateComment() {
    return View();
}

// POST: Review/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComment(Guid? id) { 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {        

        Guid userID = new Guid(Session["LoggedUserID"].ToString());            
        Guid reviewID = new Guid(id.ToString());


        CommentReview rComment = new CommentReview();

        rComment.UserId = userID;
        rComment.ReviewId = reviewID;
        rComment.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;


        db.CommentReviews.Add(rComment);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Model for CommentReview:**

```
public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
public System.Guid ReviewId { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set; }
public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

How I send data to model:

- `Id` is generating its own Guid key
- `UserID` gets its Id from `Session["LoggedUserID"]`
- `Comment` is created trough View
- The rest gets it data trough the code in controller.

**View code for CreateComment:**

```
@model xxxx.CommentReview

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateComment";
}

<h2>CreateComment</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CommentReview</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Did you forget to set the `Comment` property value ? and it is required ? Why not check the inner exceptions and see which validation failed ?

Comment: First you POST method needs to be `public ActionResult CreateComment(CommentToReview model)` so you get the values from your view. Second, you don't even send a value for the `Guid id` value because your form does not include a control for it

Comment: Can you please share your table structure with datatupes..

Comment: And since your creating a `Comment` associated with a `Review`, your GET method would need to initialize a new `Comment` and set its `ReviewId` property so the GET method would need to include a parameter for `ReviewId`

Comment: @Shyju I assume `Comment` property will get its value trough View? If not, then that's the issue. Every property is required. I'm not quite sure with inner exceptions, but I will check that out.

Comment: For that, you need to use the class CommentToReview as your method parameter so that when your form is submitted model binder will be able to map the posted form values (comment field) to your CommentToReview object.(See the signature Stephen Muecke posted in his first comment. Allso follow his second comment as well.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Aah I See.. I though I passed value from view with `(Guid? Id)`. I don't quite follow you at "you don't even send a value for the Guid id value because your form does not include a control for it". Did you mean `(Guid? Id)` part or `Guid reviewID = new Guid(id.ToString());`?

Comment: Debug your code :) The value of parameter `Guid? Id` is `null`. And `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is pointless (you do not have a model that is being bound). But there are numerous other issues with you implementation. From you previous questions, you appear to have a Details page for `Review`, so why not have the form for adding a new comment on that page, rather than a link to redirect to a new page for adding the comment?

Comment: Great it works, I changed the `(Guid? Id)` to `(CommentToReview model)`. Changed  `Guid reviewID = new Guid(id.ToString());` to  `Guid reviewID = new Guid(Model.id.ToString());`. Then added  `rComment.Comment = model.Comment;`. I can see the comment-row in db. Was this done correctly?

Comment: Only if you have added a `Guid Id` parameter for the `ReviewId` property in the GET method. It might work but its a poor implementation (you should be using a view model for a start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing the comment for a review, you should accept the review id in your GET action method as a param, create an object of `CommentReviewVm` class and set the `ReviewId` property and send to the view.

So your view model will be

```
public class CommentReviewVm
{
  public Guid ReviewId { set;get;}
  [Required]
  public string Comment { set;get;}
}
```

in your Action method,

```
public ActionResult CreateComment(Guid id)
{
  return View(new CommentReviewVm { ReviewId=id});
}
```

So when someone comes to this GET action, they need to pass the Id(which is the review id). Ex : `yourSiteName\Review\CreateComment\6ae6469d-8531-4bb6-8214-dbc65016288f`

Now in your view, you need to keep this ReviewId in a hidden field so that when you submit the form it will be available in the HttpPost action method.

```
@model CommentReviewVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.ReviewId) 
  @Html.LabelFor(f=>f.Comment)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(g=>g.Comment)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action method, use this view model as your parameter and read the values and use it for saving

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComment(CommentReviewVm model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     var m = new CommentReview { Comment = model.Comment, ReviewId=model.ReviewId };
     m.userID = new Guid(Session["LoggedUserID"].ToString());       
     m.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
     db.CommentToReviews.Add(m);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

I see you are manually setting the ReviewId(Guid) in the code. I am not sure what value you want there. If you are adding the comment againist a review, You should be getting the review id when you call the CreateComment action method (should be part of the url as i explained in the first paragraph). If that is not the case, make adjustments to the HttpPost action method to fill that value in,

Comment: It works well. The reason why I manually set `ReviewID`(Guid) in the code is because I'm pass on the selected review(`ReviewID`) from the previous page to the comment part. You got it right. Thanks.